# How do you provide custom module/loader resolve logic to webpack?

Tags: plugins, module, webpack, loader, resolve

Creating this question for reference.

The answer was provided by Webpack Core contributor [Tobias Koppers](https://github.com/sokra)

Answer (score 0):

Tobias' Answer:

> You can write a resolver plugin for this. resolve.modules is
>   translated into plugins here:
>   https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/master/lib/ResolverFactory.js#L177-L182
>
> Write a similar plugin for your own needs. You can pass it to
>   resolve.plugins.

A demo sample was created here: https://github.com/jchip/webpack-resolve-plugins-sample